# Is there a backend optimizer in LLVM?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm

I can get the optimization level from the command `llc -help`

```
-O=<char>               - Optimization level. [-O0, -O1, -O2, or -O3] (default = '-O2')
```

I want to know what the optimization does exactly.

So, I'm searching the source code of the backend optimizer.

I google it by "llvm backend optimizer", but there is no information about it, only some target-independent pass source code.

I want to know what does the optimization do for `div-rem-pars`.

It can combine two instructions of llvm IR to one instruction for assembly code.

Comment: John Regehr wrote [a long blog post that walks through this](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1603). He stops a little before the end, so you have to run the `opt` command in the posting and also look at the target-specific passes at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there are backend optimizers options in llvm. They are however not well documented [1,2]. The `TargetMachine` [3] class has functions `getOptLevel` and `setOptLevel` to set an optimization level from 0-3 for a specific target machine, so starting from there you can try to track where it is used.

[1] https://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#ssa-based-machine-code-optimizations 
[2] https://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#late-machine-code-optimizations 
[3] https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1TargetMachine.html

Comment: Now it is 2022, however `Late Machine Code Optimizations` and `SSA-based Machine Code Optimizations` is still in status `To Be Written` ... sad story